# parse html string using react html-react-parser or innerHTML? which is faster?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I receive html string from backend. I'm parsing html string using react-html-parser. But the package's import size is `174kb`. I can do the same thing using `innerHTML`. Please refer to code below. I'm setting innerHTML in useEffect so that changes are reflected when `text` changes.

- Using innerHTML

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById(`text-${_id}`).innerHTML = text;
}, [text]);
```

- using parser (I can do it in return statement itself)

```js
function SomeComponent({_id}) {
return (
    <div className="list-group-item mb-3">
      <div id={`text-${_id}`}>
        {parser(text)}
      </div>
    </div>
)}
```

I looked at the import size using `importCost` extension. Acc. to you, Which method will be faster. Is it worth using `html-react-parser`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is a JavaScript library and it internally uses JavaScript so, it will be slower.

If it's just about setting an html value, you can use `.innerHTML`, but there are [security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations) for its usage.

To avoid injection attacks(like XSS), we should sanitize the html while insertion(even if the DB is storing sanitized html).

Use a sanitizer like [`sanitize-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) or [`react-sanitize-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sanitize-html) like this

```
import SanitizedHTML from 'react-sanitized-html';

function SomeComponent({_id}) {
return (
    <div className="list-group-item mb-3">
      <div id={`text-${_id}`}
        <SanitizedHTML html={ text} />
      </div>
    </div>
)}
```

---

`html-to-react` parser (which internally calls `html-to-dom-parser`) is `react` specific and serves a different purpose. If you look at it's signature,

```
/**
 * Converts HTML string to React elements.
 *
 * @param {string} html - HTML string.
 * @param {object} [options] - Parser options.
 * @param {object} [options.htmlparser2] - htmlparser2 options.
 * @param {object} [options.library] - Library for React, Preact, etc.
 * @param {Function} [options.replace] - Replace method.
 * @returns {JSX.Element|JSX.Element[]|string} - React element(s), empty array, or string.
 */
function HTMLReactParser(html, options)
```

you can see that it returns *React element(s), empty array, or string*

---

Please note that [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not DOM parsing. Its different. AS per MDN Docs,

> The Element property innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. So would you recommend `DOMparser` or `react-html-parser`  looking at the size of package. This parser will be running inside a map loop.

Comment: The string is sanitized using `sanitize-html` when saved to db..

Comment: I have added more info to the start of the answer.

Comment: see https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml it is an alternative to using your dom query+useEffect+innerHTML. in fact, i would try to forget about using getElementById and other DOM queries...consider using react refs with the useRef hook instead if needed https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref but as noted above, also consider alternatives to using innerhtml/dangerouslysetinnerhtml...it is named as such for a reason

Comment: @naveen in their [FAQ](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser#is-this-xss-safe) `html-react-parser` have mentioned that the package doesn't sanitizes html.

Comment: @SehajArora: ah yes, they only use the for script and style tags. https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser/blob/889e9396e070a24cb7afdeb1fdad479f34d56463/lib/dom-to-react.js#L90 will update answer.